# How to implement the Google Tag Manager with a React web project and how to check it's working on every page?

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

How to implement the google tag manager in react project. I already pasted the script code on index.html and  code in the body tag.
And it also working am getting API hits on the network console.
note: I don't have any App.js in my project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH9Vb.png)

1. But I need to know is enough or not.
2. if I move to any other page by clicking the link on the home page GTM API is not in the network console?
3. How to check it's working on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspect the web page
2. Go to the console tab
3. type: "dataLayer", if this property exists, then GTM is set correctly. You just need to create the tags and triggers in GTM to track the events that you need